# PHPthumb not working - does not show image

Tags: imagemagick, phpthumb

I'm trying to use phpThumb to resize the images on my website, but it doesn't work. When using the following link, with the DEBUG MODE it gives the following result.

Of all this what catches my attention is:

> ApacheLookupURIarray () - FAILED
>
> Y
>
> ImageMagick failed with message (sh: 1:: Permission denied) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2319
>
> IP.com/phpThumb.php?src=img-noticias%2FPORTADASUGERENCIA82.jpg&zc=C&w=239&h=207&hash=a743a31b78ef3454998737fe53afdab1

Result:

```
phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

phpThumb() version          = 1.7.15-201902101903
phpversion()                = 7.2.19-0ubuntu0.19.04.2
PHP_OS                      = Linux
$_SERVER[SERVER_SOFTWARE]   = Apache/2.4.38 (Ubuntu)
__FILE__                    = /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/phpthumb.class.php
realpath(.)                 = /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt
$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]          = /phpThumb.php
$_SERVER[HOST_NAME]         = 
$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]      = 
$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]      = src=img-noticias/1.jpg&zc=C&w=239&h=207&hash=45a772ad4fb75132fa2ca0888adccc31
$_SERVER[PATH_INFO]         = 
$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]     = /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/
getenv(DOCUMENT_ROOT)       = /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/

get_magic_quotes_gpc()         = FALSE
get_magic_quotes_runtime()     = FALSE
error_reporting()              = integer     32767
ini_get(error_reporting)       = string(5)   "32767"
ini_get(display_errors)        = string(1)   "1"
ini_get(allow_url_fopen)       = string(1)   "1"
ini_get(disable_functions)     = string(384) "pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,"
get_cfg_var(disable_functions) = string(384) "pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wifcontinued,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_get_handler,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,pcntl_async_signals,"
ini_get(safe_mode)             = FALSE
ini_get(open_basedir)          = string(0)   ""
ini_get(max_execution_time)    = string(2)   "60"
ini_get(memory_limit)          = string(4)   "128M"
get_cfg_var(memory_limit)      = string(4)   "128M"
memory_get_usage()             = integer     512560

$this->config_prefer_imagemagick            = TRUE
$this->config_imagemagick_path              = NULL
$this->ImageMagickWhichConvert()            = /usr/bin/convert
[actual ImageMagick path used]              = string(16)  "/usr/bin/convert"
file_exists([actual ImageMagick path used]) = TRUE
ImageMagickVersion(false)                   = 
ImageMagickVersion(true)                    = 

$this->config_cache_directory               = string(34)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/"
$this->config_cache_directory_depth         = integer     2
$this->config_cache_disable_warning         = FALSE
$this->config_cache_maxage                  = integer     2592000
$this->config_cache_maxsize                 = integer     10485760
$this->config_cache_maxfiles                = integer     200
$this->config_cache_force_passthru          = TRUE
$this->cache_filename                       = string(159) "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache//6/63/phpThumb_cache_34.95.213.63__src63efe98491f28588805bb6a266c6c69c_pard302a481f61bc56f3b845af640c540ea_dat1571858082.jpeg"
is_readable($this->config_cache_directory)  = TRUE
is_writable($this->config_cache_directory)  = TRUE
is_readable($this->cache_filename)          = TRUE
is_writable($this->cache_filename)          = TRUE

$this->config_document_root                  = string(27)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt"
$this->config_temp_directory                 = string(34)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/"
$this->config_output_format                  = string(4)   "jpeg"
$this->config_output_maxwidth                = integer     0
$this->config_output_maxheight               = integer     0
$this->config_error_message_image_default    = string(0)   ""
$this->config_error_bgcolor                  = string(6)   "CCCCFF"
$this->config_error_textcolor                = string(6)   "FF0000"
$this->config_error_fontsize                 = integer     1
$this->config_error_die_on_error             = TRUE
$this->config_error_silent_die_on_error      = FALSE
$this->config_error_die_on_source_failure    = TRUE
$this->config_nohotlink_enabled              = TRUE
$this->config_nohotlink_valid_domains        = array(1) {   [0]=>   string(12) "34.95.213.63" } 
$this->config_nohotlink_erase_image          = TRUE
$this->config_nohotlink_text_message         = string(38)  "Off-server thumbnailing is not allowed"
$this->config_nooffsitelink_enabled          = TRUE
$this->config_nooffsitelink_valid_domains    = array(1) {   [0]=>   string(12) "34.95.213.63" } 
$this->config_nooffsitelink_require_refer    = FALSE
$this->config_nooffsitelink_erase_image      = FALSE
$this->config_nooffsitelink_text_message     = string(29)  "Image taken from 34.95.213.63"
$this->config_high_security_enabled          = TRUE
$this->config_allow_src_above_docroot        = TRUE
$this->config_allow_src_above_phpthumb       = TRUE
$this->config_max_source_pixels              = float       22369621
$this->config_use_exif_thumbnail_for_speed   = FALSE
$this->config_border_hexcolor                = string(6)   "000000"
$this->config_background_hexcolor            = string(6)   "FFFFFF"
$this->config_ttf_directory                  = string(33)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/fonts"
$this->config_disable_pathinfo_parsing       = TRUE
$this->config_disable_imagecopyresampled     = FALSE

$this->phpThumbDebug               = integer     9
$this->thumbnailQuality            = integer     75
$this->thumbnailFormat             = string(4)   "jpeg"
$this->gdimg_output                = resource
$this->gdimg_source                = resource (closed)
$this->sourceFilename              = string(46)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg"
$this->source_width                = integer     700
$this->source_height               = integer     933
$this->thumbnailCropX              = integer     0
$this->thumbnailCropY              = float       163
$this->thumbnailCropW              = integer     700
$this->thumbnailCropH              = float       606
$this->exif_thumbnail_width        = string(0)   ""
$this->exif_thumbnail_height       = string(0)   ""
$this->exif_thumbnail_type         = string(0)   ""
$this->thumbnail_width             = float       239
$this->thumbnail_height            = float       207
$this->thumbnail_image_width       = string(3)   "239"
$this->thumbnail_image_height      = string(3)   "207"
strlen($this->rawImageData)        = 0
strlen($this->exif_thumbnail_data) = 0

$this->src  = string(46)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg"
$this->new  = NULL
$this->w    = string(3)   "239"
$this->h    = string(3)   "207"
$this->f    = string(0)   ""
$this->q    = integer     75
$this->sx   = NULL
$this->sy   = NULL
$this->sw   = NULL
$this->sh   = NULL
$this->far  = NULL
$this->bg   = NULL
$this->bc   = NULL
$this->file = NULL
$this->goto = NULL
$this->err  = NULL
$this->xto  = NULL
$this->ra   = NULL
$this->ar   = NULL
$this->aoe  = NULL
$this->iar  = NULL
$this->maxb = NULL

builtin_function_exists(exif_thumbnail)          = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(gd_info)                 = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(image_type_to_mime_type) = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(getimagesize)            = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecopyresampled)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecopyresized)        = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreate)             = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromstring)   = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatetruecolor)    = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imageistruecolor)        = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagerotate)             = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagetypes)              = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(version_compare)         = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromgif)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromjpeg)     = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefrompng)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromwbmp)     = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromxbm)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromxpm)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromstring)   = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromgd)       = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromgd2)      = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagecreatefromgd2part)  = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagejpeg)               = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagegif)                = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagepng)                = TRUE
builtin_function_exists(imagewbmp)               = TRUE

gd_info.GD Version                         = string(5)   "2.2.5"
gd_info.FreeType Support                   = TRUE
gd_info.FreeType Linkage                   = string(13)  "with freetype"
gd_info.GIF Read Support                   = TRUE
gd_info.GIF Create Support                 = TRUE
gd_info.JPEG Support                       = TRUE
gd_info.PNG Support                        = TRUE
gd_info.WBMP Support                       = TRUE
gd_info.XPM Support                        = TRUE
gd_info.XBM Support                        = TRUE
gd_info.WebP Support                       = TRUE
gd_info.BMP Support                        = TRUE
gd_info.JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support   = FALSE

exif_info.EXIF Support               = string(7)   "enabled"
exif_info.EXIF Version               = string(23)  "7.2.19-0ubuntu0.19.04.2"
exif_info.Supported EXIF Version     = string(4)   "0220"
exif_info.Supported filetypes        = string(10)  "JPEG, TIFF"

ApacheLookupURIarray() -- FAILED

$_GET[src]                           = string(18)  "img-noticias/1.jpg"
$_GET[zc]                            = string(1)   "C"
$_GET[w]                             = string(3)   "239"
$_GET[h]                             = string(3)   "207"
$_GET[hash]                          = string(32)  "45a772ad4fb75132fa2ca0888adccc31"
$_GET[phpThumbDebug]                 = integer     9

$this->debugmessages:
  * phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 233
  * setParameter(config_document_root, string(27)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_disable_debug, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_high_security_enabled, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_high_security_url_separator, string(1)   "&") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_allow_src_above_docroot, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_allow_src_above_phpthumb, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_auto_allow_symlinks, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_additional_allowed_dirs, array(0) { } ) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_directory, string(34)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_disable_warning, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_directory_depth, integer     2) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_maxage, integer     2592000) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_maxsize, integer     10485760) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_maxfiles, integer     200) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_source_enabled, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_source_directory, string(41)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/source/") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_source_filemtime_ignore_local, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_source_filemtime_ignore_remote, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_default_only_suffix, string(0)   "") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_prefix, string(28)  "phpThumb_cache_34.95.213.63_") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_cache_force_passthru, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_temp_directory, string(34)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_prefer_imagemagick, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_imagemagick_use_thumbnail, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_imagemagick_path, NULL) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_max_source_pixels, float       22369621) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_output_format, string(4)   "jpeg") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_output_maxwidth, integer     0) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_output_maxheight, integer     0) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_output_interlace, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_image_width, integer     400) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_image_height, integer     100) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_message_image_default, string(0)   "") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_bgcolor, string(6)   "CCCCFF") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_textcolor, string(6)   "FF0000") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_fontsize, integer     1) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_die_on_error, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_silent_die_on_error, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_error_die_on_source_failure, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nohotlink_enabled, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nohotlink_valid_domains, array(1) {   [0]=>   string(12) "34.95.213.63" } ) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nohotlink_erase_image, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nohotlink_text_message, string(38)  "Off-server thumbnailing is not allowed") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_enabled, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_valid_domains, array(1) {   [0]=>   string(12) "34.95.213.63" } ) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_require_refer, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_erase_image, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_watermark_src, string(26)  "/demo/images/watermark.png") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_nooffsitelink_text_message, string(29)  "Image taken from 34.95.213.63") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_border_hexcolor, string(6)   "000000") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_background_hexcolor, string(6)   "FFFFFF") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_ttf_directory, string(33)  "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/fonts") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_http_user_agent, string(114) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_disable_pathinfo_parsing, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_disable_imagecopyresampled, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_disable_onlycreateable_passthru, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_disable_realpath, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_http_fopen_timeout, integer     10) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_http_follow_redirect, TRUE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_allow_local_http_src, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * setParameter(config_use_exif_thumbnail_for_speed, FALSE) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 156
  * phpThumb() v1.7.15-201902101903
http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net

ERROR: invalid hash in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4197
  * setParameter(src, string(18)  "img-noticias/1.jpg") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * resolvePath: /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg (allowed_dirs: Array
(
)
) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1180
  * resolvePath: checks disabled, returning /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1190
  * setSourceFilename(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) set $this->sourceFilename to "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 298
  * setParameter(zc, string(1)   "C") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * setParameter(w, string(3)   "239") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * setParameter(h, string(3)   "207") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * setParameter(hash, string(32)  "45a772ad4fb75132fa2ca0888adccc31") in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * setParameter(phpThumbDebug, integer     9) in file "phpThumb.php" on line 389
  * $CanPassThroughDirectly=false because $_GET[zc;hash] are set in file "phpThumb.php" on line 472
  * $CanPassThroughDirectly="0" && $phpThumb->src="/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg" in file "phpThumb.php" on line 483
  * $AvailableImageOutputFormats = array(text;ico;bmp;wbmp;gif;webp;png;jpeg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1009
  * $this->thumbnailFormat set to $this->config_output_format "jpeg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1020
  * $this->thumbnailQuality set to "75" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1037
  * SetCacheFilename() _src set from md5($this->sourceFilename) "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg" = "63efe98491f28588805bb6a266c6c69c" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3591
  * SetCacheFilename() _par set from md5(_zcC_h207_w239_dpi150_q75) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3624
  * Would have used cached file, but skipping due to phpThumbDebug in file "phpThumb.php" on line 66
  * * Would have sent headers (1): Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 21:24:38 GMT in file "phpThumb.php" on line 67
  * * Would have sent headers (2): Content-Type: image/jpeg in file "phpThumb.php" on line 69
  * * Would have sent headers (3): Location: /cache//6/63/phpThumb_cache_34.95.213.63__src63efe98491f28588805bb6a266c6c69c_pard302a481f61bc56f3b845af640c540ea_dat1571858082.jpeg in file "phpThumb.php" on line 72
  * resolvePath: /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg (allowed_dirs: Array
(
)
) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1180
  * resolvePath: checks disabled, returning /var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1190
  * $this->sourceFilename set to "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 930
  * $this->cache_filename already set, skipping SetCacheFilename() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3547
  * starting ExtractEXIFgetImageSize() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3389
  * getimagesize(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) says image is 700x933 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3399
  * $this->useRawIMoutput=true after checking $UnAllowedParameters in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1635
  * phpThumb_tempnam() returning "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/pThumb1aQo7r" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4426
  * ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(thumbnail) = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1571
  * IMuseExplicitImageOutputDimensions = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1716
  * getimagesize(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) SUCCEEDED: Array
(
    [0] => 700
    [1] => 933
    [2] => 2
    [3] => width="700" height="933"
    [bits] => 8
    [channels] => 3
    [mime] => image/jpeg
)
 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1730
  * ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(density) = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1571
  * getimagesize(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) returned [w=700;h=933;f=2] in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1745
  * source dimensions set to 700x933 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1748
  * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() starting with "700"x"933" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3368
  * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() setting w="239", h="207" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3384
  * ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(repage) = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1571
  * Skipping "+repage" because ImageMagick (v) does not support it in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1832
  * Remaining $this->fltr after ImageMagick: (array(0) { } ) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2296
  * ImageMagickSwitchAvailable(quality;interlace) = 0 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 1568
  * ImageMagick called as ('' '/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg[0]' -background '#FFFFFF' -flatten -resize 'x319' -gravity center -crop '239x207+0+0' jpeg:'/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/pThumb1aQo7r' 2>&1) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2314
  * ImageMagick failed with message (sh: 1: : Permission denied) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2319
  * deleting "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache/pThumb1aQo7r" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2351
  * ImageMagickThumbnailToGD() failed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3435
  * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() starting with "700"x"933" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3368
  * SetOrientationDependantWidthHeight() setting w="239", h="207" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3384
  * EXIF thumbnail extraction: (size=0; type=""; 0x0) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3492
  * starting SourceImageToGD() in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3750
  * starting ImageCreateFromFilename(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3665
  * ImageCreateFromFilename found ($getimagesizeinfo[2]==2) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3674
  * Calling imagecreatefromjpeg(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/img-noticias/1.jpg) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3682
  * Not using EXIF thumbnail data because $this->gdimg_source is already set in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3818
  * CalculateThumbnailDimensions() starting with [W,H,sx,sy,sw,sh] initially set to [700,933,,,,] in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3240
  * CalculateThumbnailDimensions() starting with [x,y,w,h] initially set to [0,0,700,933] in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3255
  * CreateGDoutput() returning canvas "239x207" in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 3363
  * ImageResizeFunction($o, $s, 0, 0, 0, 163, 239, 207, 700, 606) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 4401
  * memory_get_usage() after copy-resize = 489360 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 430
  * memory_get_usage() after imagedestroy = 489448 in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 432
  * AntiOffsiteLinking() says this is allowed in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2558
  * skipping AlphaChannelFlatten() because !$this->is_alpha in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 2614
  * GenerateThumbnail() completed successfully in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 444
  * CleanUpCacheDirectory() set to purge (30.0 days; 10.00 MB; 200 files) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 748
  * CleanUpCacheDirectory() skipped because "/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache//phpThumbCacheStats.txt" is recently modified in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 758
  * imageinterlace($this->gdimg_output, 1) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 480
  * RenderOutput() attempting imagejpeg($this->gdimg_output) in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 483
  * RenderOutput() completing with $this->outputImageData = 8893 bytes in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 597
  * RenderToFile(/var/www/html/aten/aten-ndt/cache//6/63/phpThumb_cache_34.95.213.63__src63efe98491f28588805bb6a266c6c69c_pard302a481f61bc56f3b845af640c540ea_dat1571858082.jpeg) succeeded in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 626
  * Would have used cached file, but skipping due to phpThumbDebug in file "phpThumb.php" on line 66
  * * Would have sent headers (1): Last-Modified: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 21:24:38 GMT in file "phpThumb.php" on line 67
  * * Would have sent headers (2): Content-Type: image/jpeg in file "phpThumb.php" on line 69
  * * Would have sent headers (3): Location: /cache//6/63/phpThumb_cache_34.95.213.63__src63efe98491f28588805bb6a266c6c69c_pard302a481f61bc56f3b845af640c540ea_dat1571858082.jpeg in file "phpThumb.php" on line 72

$this->debugtiming:
  * 1571866156.693490 : phpThumb() constructor in file "phpthumb.class.php" on line 232
  * 1571866156.693428 : phpThumb.php start in file "phpThumb.php" on line 123
  * 1571866166.694023 : phpThumbDebug[0] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 215
  * 1571866166.694079 : phpThumbDebug[1] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 272
  * 1571866166.694112 : phpThumbDebug[2] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 374
  * 1571866166.694238 : phpThumbDebug[3] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 410
  * 1571866166.694274 : phpThumbDebug[4] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 477
  * 1571866166.694283 : phpThumbDebug[5] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 564
  * 1571866166.694428 : skipped using cached image in file "phpThumb.php" on line 65
  * 1571866166.694512 : phpThumbDebug[6] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 580
  * 1571866166.694521 : phpThumbDebug[7] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 645
  * 1571866166.713554 : phpThumbDebug[8] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 655
  * 1571866166.715369 : skipped using cached image in file "phpThumb.php" on line 65
  * 1571866166.715426 : phpThumbDebug[9] in file "phpThumb.php" on line 688
  * Total processing time: 10.021998
```

Comment: Your error message seems to indicate you did not install the tool or with correct (folder?) permission

Comment: I have already established chmod -R 777
and also sudo chown -R www-data: www-data
but still not working